# facebook app test for everyone

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, app-id

I have created a facebook app. I tested it in `sandbox mode` and it's fine.

Now I want to let other people test this app in mobile phone, so I close `sandbox mode` and I found that `iPhone-5` user can't login but it still work fine in `android` phone

Here is the error log -

> session creation error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x16561ad0

I checked my `bundle id` and `app id`, it doesn't go wrong

Comment: Sorry
I forget to say that
I use prime31 socialnetworking Plugin

Comment: I delete the user in iPhone setting -> facebook
and then it is fine
Why it happened

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

Go to the settings app of your iPhone.
Open your Facebook Settings
Scroll down to your app and make sure your app allows facebook interaction.
This could happen on any device, therefore in your app you will have to make sure to handle this error correctly. I reckon you give the user feedback why Login With Facebook failed and ask the user to check their Facebook settings on their device.

```
- (void)facebookSessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error{       switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        // handle successful login here
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        // handle error here, for example by showing an alert to the user
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not login with Facebook"
                                                        message:@"Facebook login failed. Please check your Facebook settings on your phone."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used following way and its working for me :

```
-(void)openFacebookAuthentication
{
    NSArray *permission = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kFBEmailPermission,kFBUserPhotosPermission,kFBUserPublicPermission,kFBUserLikePermission, nil];

    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission];
    [FBSession setActiveSession: [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission]];
    [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        switch (status) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                [self likeFaceBook];
                break;
            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
                // prefer to keep decls near to their use
                // unpack the error code and reason in order to compute cancel bool
                NSString *errorCode = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode];
                NSString *errorReason = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedReason];
                BOOL userDidCancel = !errorCode && (!errorReason || [errorReason isEqualToString:FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue]);
                if(error.code == 2) {
                    UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kFBAlertTitle
                                                                           message:kFBAuthenticationErrorMessage
                                                                          delegate:nil
                                                                 cancelButtonTitle:kOk
                                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [errorMessage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                    errorMessage = nil;
                }
            }
                break;
                // presently extension, log-out and invalidation are being implemented in the Facebook class
            default:
                break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
        }
    }];
    permission = nil;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help
I check the phone setting -> facebook
I don't see my app on the list
It seem something wrong?